# Are there public RPC node providers?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

Are there public RPC node providers similar to [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com) or [Ankr](https://www.ankr.com), but for Bitcoin?

I just want to query basic block data and so on without having to manage my own full node. Security does not matter in my use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can get one with [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/protocols/bitcoin/). 3M calls on the free developer plan per month.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**NOWNodes** here to provide public RPC nodes for BTC/BSV/BCH/BTG.

You could [**check here our list of 100+**](https://nownodes.io/nodes)

Answer (score -1):

You can check out the RPC by [NodeReal](https://nodereal.io/api-marketplace/bitcoin-rpc). Under their Free-tier subscription, you can enjoy up to 100M Compute Units.